# How I make a pushbutton invisible in a GUI?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, user-interface, audio, wav

I want to play my wav on percussion background image area with my pushbutton, so i need my pushbutton invisible on my figure window.

My script:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[s,fs]=wavread('filename.wav');
sound(s,fs);
```

Thankyou..

Comment: I cannot understand why this would be unclear. Still worth thinking of is how to make the button visible again. This needs to be planned for.

Comment: I think the pushbutton is the wrong approach here, because if you make it invisible the Matlab way it can't be clicked anymore. You could manipulate the underlying Java, but I wouldn't recommend bothering. Rather you should determine at what position of your background image was clicked and coordinate the callbackl that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your push button invisible when you click it, set `visible`to *off* in the callback function

```
set(hObject, 'Visible', 'off')
```

To make it invisible from other parts/functions in your GUI, just replace `hObject` with the *handle* of your push button.

---

Update:

You could make a clickable image and play different sounds for different click positions. Use the callback `'ButtonDownFcn'` to trigger at a click event in the image. You can the retrive the position of the click by using the axes property  `'CurrentPoint'`. This return as 2x3 matrix with x-y-z projected coordinates. But as you are using a 2D plot you could simply pick the first 2 values, read more [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_CurrentPoint).

Then use the x/y coordinates to find out what in the image that the user clicked on and play the sound for that.

A simple example:

```
% Draw an image
figure()
imHandle = image(imread(figPath));
% Set callback function (target function could have any name)
set(imHandle,'ButtonDownFcn', @ImgClickCB);
```

And the callback function (displays the x and y coord.)

```
function ImgClickCB(hObject, ~)
clickPoint = get( get(hObject,'Parent'), 'CurrentPoint');
fprintf('Clicked at x: %0.f y: %0.f \n', clickPoint(1,1), clickPoint(1,2));
```

Comment: I think that doesn't answer the question, as you can't click the button anymore.

Comment: The question was how to make it invisable which the code above does. The button could be made visible by any other callback in the GUI.

Comment: Well, if you interpret the question that way. My interpretation is: the OP has a picture of a drumset/percussion and wants to click a drum which then makes a sound. So he wants a button on his drum, but invisible, so you can still see the drum. However, the OP should clarify.

Comment: correct, the OP(me) has a picture of a drumset/percussion and wants to click a drum which then makes a sound. So he wants a button on his drum, but invisible, so you can still see the drum. @thewaywewalk

Comment: Ok. Is it different sounds for different parts of the picture? Like one sound if you click on the hi-hat and one other for snare drums, all the same sound for the entire image?

Comment: Yes, this is to different sounds for different parts of the picture. But, the very importent  thing is how to click a drum which then makes a sound on the invisible pushbutton, so i can still see the drum without pb. @nilZ0r

Comment: @Alexandria I've updated my code with an example on how to make a "clickable image" that register where the user clicked.

Comment: I see!
Thankyou so much.. @nilZ0r

Answer (score 0):

The following example hides, and shows a pushbutton.

I created a sample, without using `guide`.
You can copy and paste the code into Matlab `m` file for execution.
Creating GUI without `guide` tool, better suit Stack Overflow site, because there is no need to attach a `fig` file.
You better use `guide` tool, because creating a GUI without it is complicated.

The following code sample hide (and show) pushbutton:

```
%TestNoGuideHideButton.m
%Create GUI with two buttons, without using GUIDE.
function TestNoGuideHideButton()
    %Create figure.    
    h.fig = figure('position', [800 400 260 80]);

    %Add button, with callback function Button1
    h.buttonOne = uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton',...
        'position',[10 20 100 40], ...
        'string' , 'Button1', ...
        'callback', {@Button1});

    %Add button, with callback function hideButton
    h.buttonTwo = uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton', ...
        'position',[150 20 100 40], ...
        'string' , 'Hide Button1', ...
        'callback', {@hideButton});


    function Button1(hObject, eventdata)
        %Modify color of Button1 to random color.
        set(h.buttonOne, 'BackgroundColor', rand(1, 3));
    end


    function hideButton(hObject, eventdata)
        is_visible = isequal(get(h.buttonOne, 'Visible'), 'on');

        if (is_visible)
            %Hide buttonOne if Visible.
            set(h.buttonOne, 'Visible', 'off');
            set(h.buttonTwo, 'string', 'Show Button1'); %Replace string.
        else
            %Restore buttonOne if hidden.
            set(h.buttonOne, 'Visible', 'on');
            set(h.buttonTwo, 'string', 'Hide Button1'); %Replace string.
        end
    end
end
```

For the problem you described above, you obviously can't add a button for showing and hiding the other button.

You can restore the button when playing finishes.

You can also add a callback function for the background figure (look for `WindowButtonDownFcn` in `guide`).
Pressing anywhere on the figure, triggers the callback, were you can restore the hidden button.

---

[image]

Comment: I edited the answer. Can you restore the button when playing ends?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [this blog entry](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/transparency-in-uicontrols) where I discussed how to manipulate the **CData** property of uicontrols.

I've added some code below to show a simple example:

```
f = figure(); % create a figure with an axes on it
pb = uicontrol('Style','checkbox', 'Units','pixels', 'Position',[10 10 300 200], ...
               'Callback',@(a,b)msgbox('play clown!'));
% read some data
data = load ( 'clown' );
% extract out the image
img = data.X;
% convert image to RGB for displaying on checkbox
img = ind2rgb(img,colormap(f)); 
% Set the cdata property of the checkbox to be the image of interest
set(pb, 'CData', img )
```

The above code creates a figure with an image of a clown which you can click on (this could be your drum).  The "button" stays there the whole time you don't need to make it invisible

Note: I use a checkbox instead of a button -> because sometimes a button can have a "border" when its in focus which can detract from the image whereas a checkbox doesn't.

I've copied the image produced below (after I clicked on the button):

[image]